# Saving jquery calculated sums and sending to php

Tags: php, jquery, variables, math, addition

I have here a jQuery calculator script that allows me to calculate the values (of a specific css class) for input boxes in each row.

I have 8 rows total, with plans to allow users to dynamically add rows in the future.

My problem is not knowing how jquery library works in it's full potential. I'm not even sure if what I'm requesting is possible, but I tried looking around and couldn't find much,

```
$(function(){
    $('specific-class').each(function() {
        $(this).keyup(function(){  
            calculateTotal($(this));
        });
    });
});

function calculateTotal(src) {
    var sum = 0;
    var sumtable = src.closest('tr'); //only calculate the current row

    sumtable.find('specific-class').each(function() {
        if(!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length!=0) {
            sum += parseFloat(this.value);
        }
    });

    sumtable.find(".qty").html(sum.toFixed(0)); //send to front
}
```

So with the above complete, I will be able to check each individual TD with the specific class and add the values together.

How do I go about storing the values of each row that gets calculated and then sending the stored variables as their own qty such as qty1,qty2,qty3 etc..?

Thank you SO Community you've been a huge help to my many questions.

Comment: You could do an ajax call on each row, inside the calculateTotal function.  But that will execute multiple times, which is not a good thing.  Ultimately you want to store in an array and then execute once

Comment: that's the way i'm going to go about it thanks KyleK!

Answer (score 0):

The only way you can send data from jquery to PHP is using [$.post](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) or [$.get](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/).
You can post you data to the same file that called it, or some separate file which has the function to manage your data.
My preferred is the second one. Keeps you project modular.